# "help" me to do my homework

Tags: meaning, verb-pattern

My brother usually tutors me and explains to me how to do the homework and I am the one who actually does it. Can I say

> My brother usually helps me (to) do my homework.

Does this sentence imply that my brother is the person who does the homework?
If so, how should I express the idea?

Comment: Yes, your sentence is the correct way to say it. (If your brother does your homework alone, but the teacher expect you to do it, then you would say: "My brother does my homework for me".)

Comment: I'd say that "... helps me **with** my homework" is more common (especially if you're the primary person doing the work), but there's nothing wrong with your sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence means that you do your homework, and your brother supports and guides you.  There is nothing wrong with the sentence.

Of course, just saying something doesn't make it true.  The student might be lying. Sentences like this might be used euphemistically notice the scare quotes in the example below.

> I got 10/10 on the calculus homework, but my brother is an MSc in maths and he, you know, "helped" me. I don't understand calculus at all!